# Multiple Spring Datasource : Consider defining bean of type ExternalJarRepository

Tags: dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, multiple-databases

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages=..,entityManagerRef=..)
@ComponentScan("com.main", "com.external.jar")
public class Application{
...
//methods defining primary datasource, transaction manager, entityManagerFactoryBean
}
```

External Jar

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.external.model", entityManagerRef=.., transactionManager=..)
public class ExternalDataConfig{

//methods defining datasource, transaction manager, entityManagerFactoryBean

}

public DataRepository extends CrudRepository<T,ID>{}

@Service 
public class ExternalService{
@Autowire
private DataRepository externalRepository;
}
```

error
`Field externalRepository in com.external.jar.ExternalService required a bean of type DataRepository'`

However the logs indicate successful scanning of both default and external repositories, not sure why the dependency injection mechanism is not able to find the bean

```
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 55ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 75ms. Found 21 JPA repository interfaces.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the default application also had a bean by the name `DataRepository` and the application settings allowed bean override

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

Renaming the `DataRepository` bean in external dependency did the trick